# How to implement retry logic?

Tags: pytransitions

I'm trying to use pytransitions to implement retransmit logic from an initialization state. The summary is that during the init state if the other party isn't responding after 1 second resend the packet. This is very similar to what I see here: https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions/pull/461

I tried this patch, and even though I see the timeouts/failures happening, my callback is only called the first time. This is true with before/after and on_enter/exit. No matter what I've tried, I can't get the retransmit to occur again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is a bit dated I'd like to post an answer since `Retry` states have been added to `transitions` in release `0.9`.
`Retry` itself will only count how often a state has been re-entered meaning that the counter will increase when transition source and destination are equal and reset otherwise. It's entirely passive and need another mean to trigger events. The `Timeout` state extension is commonly used in addition to `Retry` to achieve this. In the example below a state machine is decorated with `Retry` and `Timeout` state extensions which allows to use a couple of keywords for state definitions:

- `timeout` - time in seconds before a timeout is triggered after a state has been entered
- `on_timeout`- the callback(s) called when `timeout` was triggered
- `retries` - the number of retries before failure callbacks are called when a state is re-entered
- `on_failure` - the callback(s) called when the re-entrance counter reaches `retries`

The example will re-enter `pinging` unless a randomly generated number between 0 and 1 is larger than 0.8. This can be interpreted as a server that roughly answers only every fifth request. When you execute the example the retries required to reach 'initialized' can vary or even fail when `retries` are reached.

```py
from transitions import Machine
from transitions.extensions.states import add_state_features, Retry, Timeout

import random
import time

# create a custom machine with state extension features and also 
# add enter callbacks for the states 'pinging', 'initialized' and 'init_failed'
@add_state_features(Retry, Timeout)
class RetryMachine(Machine):
    def on_enter_pinging(self):
        print("pinging server...")
        if random.random() > 0.8:
            self.to_initialized()

    def on_enter_initialized(self):
        print("server answered")

    def on_enter_init_failed(self):
        print("server did not answer!")


states = ["init",
          {"name": "pinging",
           "timeout": 0.5,  # after 0.5s we assume the "server" wont answer
           "on_timeout": "to_pinging",  # when timeout enter 'pinging' again
           "retries": 3,  # three pinging attempts will be conducted
           "on_failure": "to_init_failed"},
          "initialized",
          "init_failed"]

# we don't pass a model to the machine which will result in the machine 
# itself acting as a model; if we add another model, the 'on_enter_<state>'
# methods must be defined on the model and not machine
m = RetryMachine(states=states, initial="init")
assert m.is_init()
m.to_pinging()
while m.is_pinging():
    time.sleep(0.2)
```